# How to install CodeNarc?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, static-code-analysis, codenarc

I am very new to stuff like that and I really can't understand the insufficient installation tutorial as a newbie. I use the IntelliJ IDEA on Windows where I like to add CodeNarc.
I downloaded Groovy, Codenarc jar and the SLF4J jar. Then I added that all into the External Libraries and tried to run it via "java org.codenarc.CodeNarc" in the IntelliJ Terminal.

But it says:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codenarc.CodeNarc
```

GROOVY_JAR="C:\Program Files\Groovy\groovy-2.5.3\lib\groovy-2.5.3.jar" is set in my Environment Variables.

What should I do now or is there an easier way to use it in IntelliJ?

Comment: Did you see this: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?correctionAllowed=true&pr=&orderBy=&search=codenarc

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but there is a problem: Plugin 'CodeNarc' failed to initialize and will be disabled

Comment: You might end up with something more relyable by using some build tool and integrate the checks there.  While making things work in an IDE is nice, you end up with this ceremony for anyone else.  And even if you're alone you might have some CI system etc, that should also be able to run things.